# Key Facebook insights metrics deprecated -- alternatives not documented?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, deprecated, metrics

Over at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ Facebook states::

```
We are deprecating some old insights. These metrics are marked as __deprecated__
throughout this document. After 12/21/2011, data for these metrics won't be available
prior to 07/19/2011 -- please download this data before this 12/21/2011. These insights
will be completely removed from API after 02/15/2012.
```

Strangely enough, this is not noted in the developer roadmap over at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

On the deprecation list are (a.o.):

- page_active_users
- page_wall_posts
- page_comment_adds
- page_like_adds
- page_fans_gender_age
- page_fans_country

My question is, what new metrics replace the metrics listed above?

Comment: Maybe `page_engaged_users` is the new one for `page_active_users`?

Comment: For the record:

`page_engaged_users` = The number of people who engaged with your Page. Engagement includes any click

`page_active_users` = The number of people who have interacted with or viewed your Page or its posts. This includes interactions from Fans and non-Fans.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any luck on what will replace `page_active_users`?

Comment: I've opened a bug about this at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/229176583829228?browse=search_4f0f5ee2c99d72223122101. Hopefully that will get some answers

Answer (score 1):

You can access this metrics via Graph API (using insights connetction for your page): `https://graph.facebook.com/{pageId}/insights`

[More information here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Facebook just aggregate some metrics. E.g. **page_fans_gender** and **page_fans_age** would be now as **page_fans_gender_age**, etc.

Comment: The graph API based insights are based upon the same (deprecated) metrics: "For more details on which insights are available please review the FQL Insights table"

Comment: Facebook just aggregate some metrics. E.g. **page_fans_gender** and **page_fans_age** would be now as **page_fans_gender_age**, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no direct replacement for `page_active_users`. I would say that `page_impressions` are closest but IMHO you have to change perspective from which you look to your data because that's evidently what Facebook does by changes in Insights API (or at least wants from us).

You can get page's posts (`https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]/posts`), posts comments (`https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]_[POSTID]/comments`) and posts likes (`https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGEID]_[POSTID]/likes`) and aggregate them by days yourself instead of using deprecated metrics `page_wall_posts`, `page_comment_adds` and `page_like_adds`.

Metrics `page_fans_gender_age` and `page_fans_country` aren't deprecated and remains in API if I look right to docs.